# Re-rendering of connect()ed component based on mapStateToProps output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In a React + Redux based project, I have a `connect()`ed component which checks user permissions via an API fetch. Fetched permissions are stored in the Redux store.

The component basically looks like `<Can check="...">...</Can>`, which talks to our API (via Redux actions) to resolve the check. If the permission is granted, `this.props.children` is rendered, `null` otherwise.

For that, `mapStateToProps()` computes a `passes` prop from authorization data in the store, which is checked in `<Can />`s `render()` method. I utilize the `ownProps` parameter to `mapStateToProps()` to get the "stuff to check" and compute the `passes` flag.

There's a bit of caching going on so I don't re-fetch on every component mount, and it basically works. Sometimes, though, the component will not re-render when the `passes` prop updates to `true` (it will however render after navigating away - using react router - and back again, so basically if the component is re-mounted).

Do `connect()`ed components re-render if the output from `mapStateToProps()` changes? The docs for `react-redux`'s `connect()` say this:

> If ownProps is specified as a second argument, its value will be the props passed to your component, and mapStateToProps will be re-invoked whenever the component receives new props.

Does that mean that passing in `ownProps` changes the rendering to only re-render if props change, or in any other way? How can I understand the note regarding memoization/returning a function from `mapStateToProps()`, or is that not even related?

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Do connect()ed components re-render if the output from mapStateToProps() changes? The docs for react-redux's connect() say this:

Output from a function can’t change by itself. Something must trigger this function to be re-evaluated in the first place.

If Redux state changes, `mapStateToProps` is re-evaluated.

If props received from parent component are shallowly unequal (have changed) *and* you use `ownProps` argument, `mapStateToProps` is also re-evaluated.

If `mapStateToProps` returned shallowly equal values to its last call, then React Redux will skip rendering. If it returned shallowly unequal values, the wrapped component will be re-rendered. It is assumed that `mapStateToProps` itself is a pure function.

> Sometimes, though, the component will not re-render when the passes prop updates to true

Please create a minimal project reproducing this and file an issue with the relevant code example.

> How can I understand the note regarding memoization/returning a function from mapStateToProps(), or is that not even related?

Not related.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. I'll check again and make sure nothing in the reducer or selector logic is actually wrong before filing an issue. The shallow equality check could be an issue.

Comment: As a quick suggestion for the [connect()](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) docs, maybe change the wording to _[...] and mapStateToProps will be re-invoked *additionally* whenever the component receives new props._

Answer (score 8):

Several things to know here:

1. `connect` will shallow-compare the output of the last `mapState` call to the current `mapState` call.  If nothing changed, it will not re-render the wrapped component.
2. By default, `connect` will only run `mapState` when the store notifies subscribers.  However, if your `mapState` function is declared as taking *two* parameters, `connect` will pass in the wrapped component's props as the second arg, allowing you to do things like `state.somePerItemData[ownProps.itemId]`.  It also then calls `mapState` any time the incoming props differ, as that may affect the output of `mapState`.
3. Reselect's default memoization only keeps a single cached value per selector function.  If you have a component that is instantiated multiple times, and all instances are sharing the same selector function instance, then the selector's memoization probably won't work the way you want, because each component instance is probably calling it with different inputs (such as their own props).  So, as a heavily advanced optimization, you can actually pass a factory function as the `mapState` argument, which could create a unique selector function instance for each component instance.

All that said, I'm afraid I don't have a specific answer for your actual question about the component not updated.  I'd probably need to see the code in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. We don't use Reselect, but I can see the issue you describe. I was missing the fact that using `ownProps` in `mapState` causes additional re-evalutation of `mapState`, not exclusive.